# Query to get data with minimum query cost

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table, structure like this:

```
   BID_FK               AccountID           Amount
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       4050
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       4050
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       4050
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       4050
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-2       500
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-2       500
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-2       500
    1                   1-1-1-1-1-1-2       500
    2                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       6580
    2                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       6580
    2                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       6580
    2                   1-1-1-1-1-1-1       6580
    2                   1-1-1-1-2-1-1       1000
    2                   1-1-1-1-2-1-1       1000
    2                   1-1-1-1-2-1-1       1000
    2                   1-1-1-1-2-1-1       1000
```

I want to query for getting out put like this :

```
AccountID         Amount(BID_FK = 1)      Amount (BID_FK = 2)
1-1-1-1-1-1-1     16200                   26320
1-1-1-1-1-1-2     2000                    0
1-1-1-1-2-1-1     0                       4000
```

With minimum query cost because I have large number of data.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this could help?

```
SELECT
AccountID,
SUM(CASE WHEN BID_FK=1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AMOUNT1,
SUM(CASE WHEN BID_FK=2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AMOUNT2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY AccountId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AccountID, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN BID_FK=1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Amount(BID_FK = 1)` 
       SUM( CASE WHEN BID_FK=2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS `Amount(BID_FK = 2)`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY AccountID
```